# Is it possible to upgrade the ram of MacBook pro 2017 from 8GB to 16GB in India?

Tags: macbook-pro

Config:
MacBook Pro (13-inch,2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)
Processor 2.3GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
Memory 8GB 2133 Mhz LPDDR3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-mid-2017-retina-display-no-touch-bar-specs.html), for this model

> 8 GB of RAM is onboard by default, but it could be upgraded to 16 GB at the time of purchase for US$200. **RAM cannot be upgraded later**.